# Handling large operations Swift

Tags: swift, string

I'm working with NSAttributed strings with large amount of characters 100 000, 1m. How should I handle operations like iterating all of the characters, changing color, foreground and background. It works fine but it's slow, it freezes for a while and then works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify them on a background thread. You can add a progress UI for the user

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    // modify attributed string
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // update UI
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this and it works fine on some of the operations.. but what about making it faster or something like that?

Comment: It's hard, you can try to use strings instead of attributed strings (and handle attributes some other way)

Comment: there is another app and also apple notes app, you can type in 1 000 000 characters and it works fine.. hmm

Comment: Work in chunks? Process only the displayed part? Cache?

Comment: You would have to provide more details about how you obtain the string and what you do with it afterwards. Question stated like now doesn't give us much to work with

Comment: let's say I want to search for a word. After finding the word in the text at different places, I blur the text, and I highlight the word.

let searchIndexes = text.ranges(of: keywordLength)
textView.textStorage.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: styles.titleTextColor().withAlphaComponent(0.10), range: NSMakeRange(0, textView.attributedText.length))
for indi in searchIndexes
 {            self.noteTextView.textStorage.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: self.styles.titleTextColor().withAlphaComponent(1), range: self.noteTextView.text.nsRange(from: indi))
}

Comment: Instead of doing it with `NSAttributedString`, you should change color of all the text and just add another label on top of it with the highlighted word. This is how safari does it in search. I don't know of the top of my head how to find a frame for that word, but I'm sure the question was already asked before